# How can I plot ± sqrt(x) in one function?

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot uses only positive square root values when `sqrt(x)` is used. Is there a way to plot both positive and negative values in the same function.

I know of a hack which is to use `f(x) = sqrt(x)` and `g(x) = -sqrt(x)` and plot them together and then adjust both functions to use the same line colors but is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can plot a parametrized curve:

```
set parametric
set trange [-10:10]
set samples 1000
plot abs(t), (t > 0 ? 1: -1) * sqrt(abs(t))
```

to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you use the parametric representation (as by Christoph's answer), you can also use the inverse function of `sqrt(t)`, which would be `t**2`, e.g.

```
set parametric
set trange [-10:10]
set samples 1000
plot t**2,t
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, a function is a mathematical object to which for every x within the domain of the function there is one and only one corresponding f(x) value. Gnuplot handles mathematical "functions". So it's not a "hack" nor is it a "problem" with gnuplot.

Comment: Gnuplot handles plots in general, not only functions. And in any case your reasoning is a bit obtuse since for this particular case x is a function of y. It being represented with the axes rotated with respect to their standard representation doesn't make it less of a function.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinions or being obtuse that's a definition. So yes, it's NOT a function if you have 2 "y"s for one "x". The parametric plot IS a function as there is only one f(t) for a give t. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29